# How to close explorer window (with all tabs) in jquery programming?

Tags: jquery

Would you please suggest me the suitable code in jQuery to close the explorer window (internet Explorer, google chrome, firefox etc)?
Currently I used some code like :
window.close(), self.close(). 
While using this code, it worked in internet explorer only to close a single tab. It did not close the whole window if it contains multiple tabs. Also this did not work for chrome and firefox. 
So, Please share your experience regarding the issue.

Comment: Do you not think that giving control of an entire browser to one tab is a huge security risk? I don't want to visit some site and have it able to close all my other tabs/windows! It is simply not possible.

Comment: window.close is plain javascript. Nothing in jQuery will make it more cross browser. It is the browser itself that decides if it allows your script to close the window.